# Sum of signature of elements of $S_n$ is $0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

> I saw in a proof that for each $n > 1$, the symmetric group $S_n$ satisfies
>   $$\sum_{g\in S_n} \varepsilon(g) =0,$$ 
>   where $\varepsilon$ is the signature.
>   Is that true?

I checked it is true for $S_2$ and $S_3$ but false for $S_4$ (I found this sum equals $-6$ by counting the conjugacy classes of $S_4$).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: $\varepsilon:S_n\to\{+1,-1\}$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: Alternative hint: The sum is the determinant of the $n \times n$-matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's true. Let $x$ be any transposition, then $$\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{g \in S_n} \varepsilon(g) &= \sum\limits_{g \in S_n} \varepsilon(xg) \\
&= \sum\limits_{g \in S_n} -\varepsilon(g) \\
&= -\sum\limits_{g \in S_n} \varepsilon(g).
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is very elegant!

Answer (score 1):

If *signature* means *sign*, then the sum is zero because exactly half the elements of $S_n$ have sign $+1$ and half the elements have sign $-1$.