# Representation theory. Illustration of a theorem

Tags: representation-theory

I read a book and it said:

> **Theorem 2.3** The characters of irreducible representations are orthonormal.

Can someone provide a detailed example to this theorem?

Thank you.

Comment: Irreducible representation of what? There is more than one theorem, see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Character_orthogonality_theorem).

Comment: I know this book and don't have to look at chapter 2.3. You should add representations of *(finite) groups* in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest example would most likely be the trivial character and the signum on $S_n$. They are both irreducible, so the fact that they are orthogonal means that
$$\sum_{\pi \in S_n} sign(\pi) = 0,$$
which should be relatively easy to show (assuming $n \geq 2$ of course).

As this is a central result in representation theory, I would check the book for further examples or exercises. The result will surely come up at a few more places, e.g. when determining character tables.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188793/sum-of-signature-of-elements-of-s-n-is-0